# recorded vba code does not change legend colour in chart

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code is what I got when I recorded a macro to change the colour of series in my legend.

When I run it, it does not change the colour? Additionally is there a way I can specify the series, rather than just, series1,series2, instead I want to specify Apples, Oranges, etc..

My code is as follows:

```
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
```

Comment: Avoid  [the-macro-recorder-curse](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/)!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following...

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    With .Legend.LegendEntries(1).LegendKey.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End With
```

Hope this helps!